# PowerShell : Delete a row according to the length of a value in a specific column

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file where I have multiple rows. I only want to have the rows where the character length of NumInventaire (one of the columns) is strictly equal to 6.

Here is an example of data lines :

```
Avis,NumInventaire,OS,Statut,Client
123456,LM-001,78954,In Progress,M. Dupont
89541,PLATEAU 58 RELEASE,892156,To do,M. Durand
99962,BU-564,223621,Done,M. Martin
96654,ZONE GRILLAGE,75546,Done,M. Michel
56456,P45 RELEASE,75445,To Do, M. Marsan
74654,JH-654,78545,In Progress, M. Blanc
```

I have this line of code at the moment :

```
Import-Csv "$treatmentfolder\data.csv" | where {$_.NumInventaire.length -eq 6} | Export-Csv -Path "$treatmentfolder\new.csv" -notypeinfo
```

It works for the data up there but my data file has 1000 rows and 28 columns. Only one row is kept. How do I get all the rows ?

Comment: I edited my post ^^

Comment: Hmmm, this `Import-Csv .\foo.csv|where {$_.NumInventaire.length -eq 6} |Export-Csv bar.csv -notypeinfo` works for me with your data. I get three rows

Comment: Weird... The csv I have has more than a 1000 rows and more columns than that. But it would just get one row. There is no logic since there are other rows before and after that one where `$_.NumInventaire.length -eq 6`

Comment: I tested with the data that I gave you and it does work. I don't understand why it doesn't for a bigger file....

Comment: It's hard to help you without the faulty csv. Maybe there is some `, ` where it shouldn't appear?

Comment: Sorry, the data I have is a confidential so it's hard for me to give an example :/

Comment: No Problem. But please check if the csv is valid, e.g. no unwanted comma anywhere. You could easily check this by opening the csv in Excel (or better Open/Libre Office, better for csv handling) and check if there is an unwanted column somewhere

Comment: Okay, I got it. Powershell put some quotation marks in odd ways in my data.csv file. Everything works now. ^^ Thanks anyway for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the net length I suggest inserting `.Trim("'")` and/or `.Trim('"')` into your command.

```
Import-Csv "$treatmentfolder\data.csv" | 
  where {$_.NumInventaire.Trim('"').Trim("'").length -eq 6} | 
    Export-Csv -Path "$treatmentfolder\new.csv" -notypeinfo
```

You could also counter check treating the file as text:

```
gc "$treatmentfolder\data.csv" | where {$_.Split(',')[1].Trim('"').Trim("'").Length -eq 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you find the right way, and the problem is you missed one parameter.

```
Import-Csv "$treatmentfolder\data.csv" |`
where {$_.NumInventaire.length -eq 6} |`
Export-Csv -Path "$treatmentfolder\new.csv" -notypeinfo -Append
```

One thing I'm not sure: you may get repeated headers, if it is, please try `Get-Content` and `Add-Content`.
Have a try, and let us know if it works. :)

Comment: Thank you but `-Append` doubles the same data.